unable to use \cmidrule in lualatex-dev (2024)
I am encountering the following error when using the \cmidrule and \DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III,table}} commands within my document while using lualatex-dev (2024).

It's working fine when I use \DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III}}.
My MWE is below
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III,table}}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}




\begin{table}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}lll@{}}
first1 & first2 & first3\\\toprule
Second1 & Second2 & Second3\\\cmidrule{2-2}
Third1 & Third2 & Third3\\
Fourth1 & Fourth2 & Fourth3\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}


\end{document}


thanks for the example, I can confirm. We don't yet claim to support all contributed packages, but booktabs mostly works with tabbing. internally cmidrule is really a table row and its confusing things but should be fixable...

See this github issue with a possible fix https://github.com/latex3/tagging-project/issues/69

This has been fixed in the current dev formats but you have to additionally load the firstaid module.
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III,table,firstaid}}
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}lll@{}}
first1 & first2 & first3\\\toprule
Second1 & Second2 & Second3\\\cmidrule{2-2}
Third1 & Third2 & Third3\\
Fourth1 & Fourth2 & Fourth3\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}

